# How does Wordpress interprets comments?

Tags: wordpress

How does Wordpress interprets comments written on start of some files as `style.css` and `index.php` etc as developers says that comments are non-executable code?

Comment: As code comments. If you want a better answer, please update your question to be a more detailed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply reads php/css files as text files and parses out needed info from them.

Comment: Which type of language or method is used for this purpose can you elaborate please.. thanks for your response, I do not know how does it work...  how can it interprets file as text because extensions are php or css not txt??

Comment: @user3775044 it doesn't interpret them, it just reads them as plain text with `fopen` or `file_get_contents`. I can't not give you specific method, you should look for it in Core WordPress code